# ASP.NET: Custom client-side validator for "one of two fields must be filled"?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Can you tell me if there anybody has implemented a **custom validator for checking that one of two (or N)** input fields are filled?

```
   "Insert phone number or email address"
```

I'm using ASP.NET (Ajax) 3.5, the ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender (and jQuery if it's necessary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, sure, about 10 minutes later I found this Code Project article **[Multiple Fields Validator - An ASP.NET Validation Control by Adam Tibi](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MultipleFieldsValidator.aspx)** by myself:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I just did this (requires jQuery):

JS:

```
function validatePhoneOrEmail(source, args) {
    if ($("[id$='txtEmail']").val() == "" && $("[id$='txtTel']").val() == "") 
        args.IsValid = false;
    else
        args.IsValid = true;
}
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" 
    ClientValidationFunction="validatePhoneOrEmail" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a telephone number or email address">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

I don't have any server-side validation for this, but I'm assuming a similar function in the server would be pretty easy to create.

Comment: Obiviously you could one-line the validator if you wanted :P

Comment: Thanks, this one worked for me. I was almost there, just needed to remove the `ControlToValidate` attribute otherwise it wouldn't validate period.

Comment: thanks this great tip. good works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not one to push commercial products here but when it comes to asp.net validation you would do yourself an incredible disservice not to take a look at peterblum.com. Best asp.net control package bar none...Hanselmans take on them -

"Not an add-in but rather a complete re-imagining of the ASP.NET Validation Framework. There's a learning curve, but it will change the way you write pages. Also check out his Visual Security Security and Peter'sDatePackage. His documentation is legendary."

Answer (score 0):

Code project also has this control (by yours truly):
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/AtLeastOneOfValidator.aspx

Comment: I flagged this as 'not an answer' because one can't see the source code without logging in to codeproject.

Comment: @ChrisW That's odd. I'm not a codeproject member, but I had no issue viewing the content. (However, I have closed this question as off-topic, since it's a collection of off-site recommendations.)

Comment: Yeah, I just put it there because neither github or codeplex existed yet at the time.